# Configuring Proftpd on MacOSX

Tags: macos, proftpd

I am installing Proftpd on Mac 10.8
I am executing the commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/proftpd
make
sudo make install
```

But when I execute the command sudo make install, the follow error is displayed:

> xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch , or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.
>   install: child process failed: xcrun strip - /usr/local/proftpd/sbin/proftpd
>   make: *** [install-proftpd] Error 70

Is necessary have installed xCode (last version) on my environment? or what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all of Xcode installed, but you do at least need to have the Command Line Tools for Xcode. Without them, your system does not have a C compiler installed.

You can download this package at: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/